# stop / shutdown failed: not bound to TTS engine

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have an android activity that uses TTS but when I exit it get a leaked Service Connection error in Logcat.  Above the leaked Service error I get a statement that:

```
stop failed: not bound to TTS engine
shutdown failed: not bound to TTS engine
```

My onStop and onDestroy look like this:
EDIT Code:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (tts != null) {
    tts.stop();
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I trigger the TTS when the user pushes a button (TTS does work ok, I am just trying to fix the service connection error)

```
if (v == speakButton && ttscrashprotect == 1) {   
    String text = inputText.getText().toString();
    if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }
```

This is my onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            //sucess with TTS create it
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
        else {
            //missing TTS so install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
```

TTS is working fine and I can see the engine being called in logcat, but for some reason the `tts.stop()` and `tts.shutdown()` aren't bound to the same engine.

EDIT2:  It would seem I am connecting to the TTS engine and service more than one time.  Each time the text that I want TTS to say within the activity then another connection is made to the TTS engine and TTS service.

My TTS code when the text changes looks like this:

```
if (v==nextButton && progressL1<100) {
    Video.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //hide the video view

    progressL1= progressL1 + 10;
    //increase progress by 10 and then load the new files
    //load the TTS text data from Asset folder progressL1 txt file
    Advanced.this.loadDataFromAsset(progressL1);
    //try some tts stuff here
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

TTS is triggered from the `v == speakButton` code above.

Comment: Why would you call `tts.stop()` and `tts.shutdown()` twice, in both `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`?

Comment: I tried adding the onStop() as I was still getting the error with the .stop and .shutdown called from onDestroy().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `tts.shutdown()` twice, just in `onDestroy()` will be sufficient.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested and have discovered a different issue - question edited.

Comment: Why don't you just reuse the same `tts` object, instead of creating a new one for each text you want to convert to speech?

Comment: Totally valid - I dont know how.  Could you offer a suggestion within my code how I might do that?

Comment: really hard to make a proper suggestion here since I don't have a global vision of your code and what you are intending to do, but you should stick to only one `TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA` call (for example, in `onCreate()`), create your `TextToSpeech` instance in `onActivityResult()` (just like you do now), and from there only use `tts.speak()` when you need to TTS some text.